R3InjectorError when adding AuthGuard in my Ionic Angular project with firebase
Okay so I am building a small project and I ran into an issue when trying to add AuthGuard. So I already did this in some of my other apps and it worked fine (Used angular and firebase aswell not Ionic tho). But I keep getting this error no matter what I do:
main.ts:14 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector)[AuthGuard -> AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:1654:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1100:40)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1106:60)
    at Object._AngularFireAuth_Factory [as factory] (angular-fire-compat-auth.mjs:150:84)
    at core.mjs:3219:47
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:866:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:3218:21)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3082:33)

The problem is if I remove the authguard the app works fine I can log in register users everything so I know the environment is correct. but as soon as I add auth guard I get this error so I suspect its that. I tried asking for help chatGPT without any luck so I hope someone here will now what the problem is.
This is the code I have tried and used:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      map(user => !!user),
      tap(loggedIn => {
        if (!loggedIn) {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}

And this is for routes:
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard'; 

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadComponent: () => import('./home/home.page').then(m => m.HomePage),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] 
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    loadComponent: () => import('./pages/main/main.page').then(m => m.MainPage),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] 
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadComponent: () => import('./pages/login/login.page').then(m => m.LoginPage)
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    loadComponent: () => import('./pages/register/register.page').then(m => m.RegisterPage)
  },
];

Here is also for login for example if it helps in anyway:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CoreModule } from 'src/app/core/core.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    CoreModule,
    RouterModule 
  ]
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  loginForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required]],
      rememberMe: [false]
    });
  }

  async login() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      try {
        await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password);
        this.router.navigate(['/main']);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Login error', error);
      }
    }
  }
}

I tried adding core.module.ts since I am using newer version of angular that uses standalone components. This is that:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase), // Initialize Firebase
    AngularFireAuthModule, // Import AngularFireAuthModule
    IonicModule.forRoot(), // Ensure IonicModule is imported
  ],
  exports: [
    AngularFireModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {}

But nothing worked so I would ask for any help if anybody knows anything. Thanks in advance
